# How to Integrate mobileAppTracker to corona Project( Running on xcode-editor)

Tags: ios, objective-c, lua, coronasdk, mobile-app-tracker

I am iOS developer. I have a Corona project (code in lua language) .  i need to add mobileAppTracker framework to corona Project. for that process i do following step.

1) First i migrate corona project to corona-xcode editor.

Now, how can i add & implement mobileAppTracker.framework to corona-xcode project ?

(corona xcode project can't contain appdelegates, view controllers, Targets and build settings also)
i am getting frustrating about this. Please help me anyone.

Comment: mobileAppTracker documentation,they mentioned no need to add mobileAppTracker.framework for corona project, u just add mobileAppTracker.a file .                   So i added mobileAppTracker.a file to our project.? but how can i set advertiser id ,conversion key and measureSession to mobileAppTracker please help me anyone @malar

Comment: Finally i done Using Corona Enterprise.